# rhnsd service not working after upgrade from 5.0.37 to 5.0.44

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, centos-7

I recently upgraded rhnsd package from 5.0.37 to 5.0.44 when it is in 0.37 version it used to be running as one process rhnsd.service but from 0.44 it split into two services one is rhnsd.timer and other rhnsd.service. Only rhnsd.timer process is in the active state and rhnsd.service is always dead. I can't see any logs in /var/log/messages. Is there any solution to write logs out and see the activity of rhnsd processes.

Machine : centos 7.6 , x86_64

**Output from 5.0.37**
rhnsd.service - LSB: Starts the Spacewalk Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/rhnsd; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-05-30 14:36:22 CDT; 2 weeks 0 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
 Main PID: 5551 (rhnsd)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 10.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/rhnsd.service
           └─5551 rhnsd

**Output from 5.0.44**
process output via systemctl
● rhnsd.service - Spacewalk Server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rhnsd.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2019-06-14 17:20:26 UTC; 46min ago
  Process: 13792 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rhn_check (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 13792 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 14 17:20:26 XXXXXXX systemd[1]: Started Spacewalk Server daemon.

rhnsd.timer - Spacewalk periodic check timer
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rhnsd.timer; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (waiting) since Tue 2019-06-11 20:47:40 UTC; 2 days ago

Jun 11 20:47:40  systemd[1]: Started Spacewalk periodic check timer.

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for an answer to this for several days now. I came across this question during my search and decided to come back and post an answer here when I finally found it.

### Explanation

The rhnsd 5.0.44 package is part of the client for Spacewalk 2.9. Part of the update from the client for 2.8 to the client for 2.9 involved moving from an always-running service daemon (`rhnsd.service`) to a systemd timer (`rhnsd.timer`). If enabled and started, `rhnsd.timer` will periodically start `rhnsd.service` (really it just runs the `rhn_check` binary) to check for updates from the Spacewalk server.

### To Fix Clients not Checking in or Performing Scheduled Tasks

```
systemctl enable rhnsd.timer
systemctl start rhnsd.timer
```

### Modifying Client Check-In Times

The configuration for `rhnsd.timer` is in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/rhnsd.timer`. The default for version 5.0.44 is `OnCalendar=00/4:00`, which means that the timer will start rhnsd.service every day, every 4 hours on the hour, starting at midnight. If you wanted to make it run every 4 hours at half past the hour, you would change it to `OnCalendar=00/4:30`. Likewise, to make it run every 2 hours on the hour, you would use `OnCalendar=00/2:00`.

### References

[A Spacewalk mailing list thread on the topic](https://www.redhat.com/archives/spacewalk-list/2019-April/msg00069.html)

[An explanation of systemd timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers)

[A more succinct description of systemd timer values](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396673)